# Maven dependency exclusion doesn't seem to work

Tags: maven

I have a Maven project depending on couple other Maven projects. I am using Spring 3.1.1 in my project and dependent projects have 3.0.6. I am trying to exclude Spring 3.0.6 when deploying since having both isn't possible. I have added an explicit exclusion in my POM for that but for some reason I still see old version of spring core jars in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder when I start the Tomcat server. Can someone point me out where I am going wrong. Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<project>
   ....
<properties>
    <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
</properties>
<dependency> 
        <groupId>com.test.abc</groupId> 
        <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
         <version>1.0</version>
         <type>war</type>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>            
      </dependency> 
          <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-xml</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-m2</version>
    </dependency>
        ....    
       </project>
```

Comment: are you sure you excluded it from all dependencies which depended on it?

Comment: yes i did. i am going crazy with this already.

Comment: what is your output if you run `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: weird thing is my dependency tree output doesn't show those spring 3.0.6 jars in it. do you want me to post the output?

Comment: if the dependency:tree did not show them, then they are not being included.  did you run `mvn clean` after you added the exclusion?

Comment: yes.. tried it one more time but no luck. :(

Comment: post the output of `dependency:tree`

Comment: @lucas ..thnx for the response.. our team has decided to upgrade the other ones for now..

Comment: How is this webapp deployed to Tomcat?  Are you sure `WEB-INF/lib` is cleaned on deploy?

Answer (score 4):

Your dependency type is war so there is no resolution happening here. Maven overlays the war contents over your project.

When the war is published to repository, the artifact will contain dependent libraries in WEB-INF lib folder. During overlay it does not treat lib folder any different from any static resource unless you tell it to exclude in different way.Check 'overlay' property [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I thought I excluded the right dependency. With eclipse, on dependency hierarchy tab you can right click on it and click exclude artifact and it excluded the right dependency (they both had the same artifactId but different groupId)