# Configuring jetty:run to use the "final" lib folder

Tags: maven, maven-3, war, maven-jetty-plugin, maven-war-plugin

I have a Maven project using a `war` overlay. As outlined [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15035481/724361), one problem with WAR overlays is that they seem to effectively sidestep Maven's dependency resolution. This results in build and/or runtime verification errors.

Fortunately, there is a solution - using the `overlay/excludes` configuration directives. This ensures that the resultant `WAR` will only have what you want.

However, it seems that the `jetty:run` uses the `war` plugin's `work` directory for library resolution (which does contain the "bad" JAR).

The problem is avoided by using either `jetty:run-war` or `jetty:run-exploded`.

However,

- as **most of our projects run fine using `jetty:run`**,
- and **`jetty-run` with scanInterval is very convenient during development**,

**I'd like to know whether it's possible to add some configuration changes to the POM that would force the `run` goal to use the target `lib` folder?**

---

For illustration purposes, here's the specific example:

- the project uses the `org.apache.solr:solr:3.6.2` overlay,
- the overlay includes an old version of Guava, `r05`, while our code uses a more recent one, `14.0.1`,
- as stated before, while the target artifact `war` is fine, `jetty:run` includes the `r05` version into the classpath, which causes verification errors in our code.

Here's the example POM:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr.archetype.examination</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>A Solr project</name>

    <properties>
        <solr.version>3.6.2</solr.version>
        <solr.port>8983</solr.port>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
            <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
            <version>${solr.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
            <artifactId>solr</artifactId>
            <version>${solr.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
            <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
            <version>${solr.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <overlays>
                        <overlay>
                            <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
                            <artifactId>solr</artifactId>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/guava-r05.jar</exclude>
                            </excludes> 
                        </overlay>
                    </overlays>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.25</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
                    <contextPath>/solr</contextPath>
                    <connectors>
                        <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                            <port>${solr.port}</port>
                            <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                        </connector>
                    </connectors>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>solr.data.dir</name>
                            <value>target/data</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```